# i want to redraw UItablecell when its clicked

Tags: iphone, ios

i am using a product list and showing in a table view, i want to show the product details when the cell is selected, it could be done to redraw the particular on did select event or attaching some other uiview on selecting of cell, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to push the next viewcontroller with the detail view. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html, it should be in the Xcode documentation too.

Comment: i know how to push the new view controllers, but my question is that i want to show the few lines of details of the particular product whos cell is clicked.

Comment: and i want to increase te height of particular cell and reload the cell with detail text.

Comment: Have you tried `reloadData` and then in that specific row you use a different layout?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's best for you to use your own custom `UITableViewCell` objects. Then, you can modify them when the delegate from your `UITableView` is called:

```
- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

Here you can modify the cell as you please.

Hope this helps!